# Can't install php 5.4 on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: server, software-installation, php

I'm trying to install php5.4 but i can't find it in the packages, I added also paa or ppa repository and nothing... I specifically need 5.4 cause all the php files aren't working so well on latest versions.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 5.4 security support has ended on [3. September 2015](https://secure.php.net/eol.php).  You should upgrade your script the latest supported PHP version.  At the time of writing this, the recommended version is at least PHP 5.6 that will be supported until [31. December 2018](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Running unsupported version of PHP is strongly discouraged as the obsolete version have or will have security vulnerabilities.  The aforementioned PPA is kept only for historic reasons and I will not produce any new builds of PHP 5.4 for any Ubuntu version.

You can still use it to install latest PHP 5.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but again it's strongly discouraged to do so.  See my answer to similar request for PHP 4: [Installing obsolete libapache-mod-php4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753960/installing-obsolete-libapache-mod-php4/766377#766377)

Comment: thank you very much. i'm using php5.5 now and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following set of command to add PPA for PHP 5.4 in your Ubuntu system and install PHP 5.4

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5
```

To check the installed version, just type:

```
php -v
```

Source : [How to Install PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5 or PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04, 14.04 or 12.04 using PPA](http://tecadmin.net/install-php5-on-ubuntu/#)

Comment: Error  Package 'php5' has no installation candidate, Package php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

Comment: @user6389884, Maybe this question will help [Can't install php5 on Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/756879/cant-install-php5-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: still nothing... they say you need to downgrade from ubuntu 16.04 to 14.